# PlaygroundPage has no member assessmentStatus

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I'm trying to assign an `assessmentStatus` like so:

```
PlaygroundPage.current.assessmentStatus = .pass(message: "Great job!")
```

However I keep getting the error

```
PlaygroundPage has no member assessmentStatus
```

I've imported `PlaygroundSupport` and statements like `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = myController` work just fine.

The Apple docs claim that `assessmentStatus` exists:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/swift_playgrounds_doc_format/XCPlaygroundPage.html

But clicking on `PlaygroundPage` and going to it's definition shows that there really is no member `assessmentStatus` as shown in this screen shot:

[image]

Can someone help get me sorted?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That feature only works with the `Playgrounds app` on the iPad and not `Playground` from `Xcode`. You can download the app on your iPad [here](https://www.apple.com/swift/playgrounds/)

Later edit: See [this](https://andyshep.org/2016/08/2016-08-05-making-assessments-in-swift-playgrounds/) article too

Comment: This is probably true.  Is there any official doc discussing this distinction?